# First Post Pause function and the 5 min Issue

Tags: designer-workflow, designer, sharepont

Hello guys I wan't to make my workflow pause for 1 day then restart:

[image]

but it keeps sending emails every 5 mins

I am lost

UPDATE!!

this is how it looks now but it is not working

[image]

Comment: append pause before if or move pause up inside if

Comment: How many servers do you have in the farm? Do you have WFE and App servers? Or is it just one server?

Comment: thx for the reply! I have one server hosting SharePoint and another one for the Workflow manager server and one for the WCA (office online)

Comment: when you fire your workflow?,which time?

Comment: Or you run your workflow Once in a day ?

Comment: Hi Nikhil Bhavni,
It seems to be working for now thx!

Comment: Hello!
It doesn't send mail after the pause I think when it find an empty day it stops!